# How to Update or Create Heroku Config Var from Python

Tags: python, heroku

I have a python worker process for my Heroku app. I need it to be able to update and add Config Vars for the application but I'm not sure how to do it. It's easy to read existing ones and update temporary values using `os.environ` but that doesn't cause them to save and be viewable on the settings page of my app on heroku.com.

Comment: "I need it to be able to update and add Config Vars"—why do you think you need this? This is very unusual, and there is almost certainly a better solution. This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

The code starts by importing the heroku library.
Then it creates a client object and assigns the API key to it.
It then gets an app object from that client, which is assigned to the variable app .
If os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_NAME'] exists in the config of this app, then it will assign os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_VALUE'] to that value in the configuration file.
Otherwise, if there is no such var name or value defined in this app's configuration file, then it will create a new one with those values and save them as variables called config vars .
The code is used to set the configuration variable HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_NAME in the app.config file to os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_VALUE'] .
The following code will then create a new configuration variable with the name HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_NAME if it doesn't exist and set its value to os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_VALUE'] .

```
 import os

 import heroku

 client = heroku.from_key(os.environ['HEROKU_API_KEY'])

 app = client.apps[os.environ['HEROKU_APP_NAME']]

 if os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_NAME'] in app.config:

 app.config[os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_NAME']] = 
 os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_VALUE']

 else:

 app.config_vars.create(os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_NAME'], 
 os.environ['HEROKU_CONFIG_VAR_VALUE'])
```

Comment: Assuming you are referring to [the `heroku` module on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/heroku/), it hasn't been updated since _2013_. [It is long deprecated](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py) and shouldn't be used for any reason in 2022.